# Component cant access state stored in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am facing a problem where my Array component cant access the state "count" stored in a redux store, I have verified that the store is connected and its showing up in the react dev tools.The Array component is supposed to take the count and genearate a random array based on it.

This is my App.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import './App.css';
    
    //redux
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import store from './store';
    
    //components
    import Array from './components/Array'
    
    const App=()=>{
      return(
      <Provider store={store}>
       
           <Array/>
       
      </Provider>
      )
    }

export default App;
```

This is the array component which cant access the "count" state.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

//actions
import {generate} from '../actions/genRanArray';

const Array=({count,generate})=>{

    const onClick=(e)=>{
        console.log(count);
        console.log('count displayed');
        generate(count)
    }
    return(
        <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Click Me!</button> 
    )
}

Array.propTypes={
    count:PropTypes.number,
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{ return{
    count: state.count
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{generate})(Array);
```

EDIT!!!
This is my "generate" action, It generates a random array .

```
import { GENERATE_RANDOM_ARRAY } from "./types";

//generate random no

    const generateRandomNumber=(min,max)=>{
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
       
    
    }
    //generate random array
    export const generate=(count)=>dispatch=>{      
            const temp=[];
            for(let i=0;i<count;i++){
                // temp.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+200);
                temp.push(generateRandomNumber(50,200))
            }
     console.log(temp);
     dispatch({
         type:GENERATE_RANDOM_ARRAY,
         payload:temp
     })
    }
```

This is the reducer,
The payload is the array generated stored in the states

```
import { GENERATE_RANDOM_ARRAY } from "../actions/types";

const initialState={
    array:[],
    arraySteps:[],
    colorKey:[],
    colorSteps:[],
    currentSteps:0,
    count:10,
    delay:100,
    algorithm:'',
    timeouts:[],
};



//reducer
function stateReducer(state=initialState,action){
    const {type,payload}=action;
    switch(type){
        case GENERATE_RANDOM_ARRAY:
            return {
                ...state,
                array:payload,
                arraySteps:payload,
            };
        default:return state;
        
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!.

Comment: Please show detail about `generate` action and reducer

Comment: have you tried to rename the `Array` component to something but the JS reserved word?

Comment: tried it same error

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Middleware allows for side effects to be run without blocking state updates**

use **thunk** middleware

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export default function App() {
  const store = createStore(
    stateReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Array />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```